# Calculating the Taylor polynomial of $x·\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am trying to calculate the 4th degree Taylor polinomial of the function f(x) = x·ln(x) at the point x = 1.

One way to do it is to simply substitute:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{4}\frac{f^{(k)}(1)}{k!}·(x-1)^{k}= f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)+\frac{f''(1)}{2}(x-1)^2+\frac{f'''(1)}{3!}(x-1)^3+\frac{f''''(1)}{4!}(x-1)^4 $$

Which evaluates to

$$ (x-1)+\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2-\frac{1}{6}(x-1)^3+\frac{1}{12}(x-1)^4 $$

I've been told that another way to do it is to calculate the Taylor polynomial of ln(x) and multiply it with the Taylor polynomial of x (which is x), and then eliminate all the terms that have a higher degree than 4.

The 4th degree Taylor polynomial of g(x)=ln(x) at the point x = 1 is

$$ (x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}-\frac{(x-1)^4}{4} $$

If we multiply by x we get:

$$ x(x-1)-\frac{x(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{x(x-1)^3}{3}-\frac{x(x-1)^4}{4} $$

Here we only have one term with a higher degree than 4, which is $ -\frac{x^{5}}{4}$. So if we substract this term from the above expression we get a 4th degree polynomial.

$$ x(x-1)-\frac{x(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{x(x-1)^3}{3}-\frac{x(x-1)^4}{4} + \frac{x^{5}}{4} $$

However, when I graph both polynomials it is very clear that they are not the same. The one obtained using the first method is correct, but the second one is not.

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $x$ at $1$ is $1+(x-1)$, not $x$.

Comment: But aren't all the following terms zero, since the derivatives of higher order than 1 are all 0?

Comment: Multiplying with $x$ would work if we would have the Taylor series at $a=0$ , in other words , if we would have a MacLaurin series.

Comment: @Unnamed I don't understand your question. Did writing $x$ instead of $0+x$, or even $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \delta_{1,j} x^j$, bother you?

Comment: You first wrote "1 + (x-1)...." instead of "1 + (x-1)" , and I thought that you meant that there were more terms in the polynomial.

Comment: @Unnamed Those dots (which are no longer there) were meant as continuation dots in the textual sense. I generally don't use them in summations because I think that hinting at patterns is a subpar form of mathematical communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taylor polynomial of order $4$ of $x$ at $1$ is $1+(x-1)$. And the product of $1+(x-1)$ with
$$
(x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}-\frac{(x-1)^4}{4}
$$
becomes
$$
(x-1)+\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2-\frac{1}{6}(x-1)^3+\frac{1}{12}(x-1)^4
$$
after eliminating the term with degree $5$.